# How do you Test that a IEnumerable<SomeClass> has all items of class SomeClass in MBunit?

Tags: mbunit

How do you Test that a IEnumerable has all items of class SomeClass in MBunit?

I've once used Visual Studio Unit Test Framework and found `CollectionAssert.AllAreInstancesOfType` or something to check that.

But how do I do it in MBunit?

Comment: Do you mean "type SomeClass or derived"? Because an IEnumerable<SomeClass> cannot have a SomeOtherClass in it unless SomeOtherClass is derived from SomeClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see anything in the MBUnit [`CollectionAssert`](http://mbunit.tigris.org/source/browse/mbunit/src/MbUnit.Core/Framework/CollectionAssert.cs?view=markup&content-type=text%2Fvnd.viewcvs-markup) Class that could help you here

You can easily write your own though (untested).

```
public class MyCollectionAssert
{
  public void CollectionAssert(IEnumerable source, Predicate<object> assertion)
  {
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
       Assert.IsTrue(assertion(item));
    }
  }

  public void AllAreInstancesOfType(IEnumerable source, Type type)
  {
    return CollectionAssert(source, o => o.GetType() == type);
  }
}
```

I assuming you actually mean IEnumerable and not `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` which the compiler enforces the type safety of.  To use this extension method call:

```
MyCollectionAssert.AllAreInstancesOfType(myList, typeof(SomeClass));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff Brown](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/), the lead developer of the Gallio project has opened an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=483) for that request. We are going to implement a few dedicated assertions: `Assert.ForAll` and `Assert.Exists`. They should be available in the next release of Gallio/MbUnit (v3.1) but you will be able to use them sooner by downloading the daily build in some days (Stay tuned).

**Edit:**
Starting from [Gallio/MbUnit v3.1.213](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables/), you can use `Assert.ForAll<T>(IEnumerable<T>, Predicate<T>)`.

```
[Test]
public void AllMyObjectsShouldBeStrings()
{
  var list = GetThemAll();
  Assert.ForAll(list, x => x.GetType() == typeof(string));
}
```